# Show reserve information and not many2many_tags [Odoo 15]

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-15

I'm having some trouble with an xml notebook. I want to show all the information from a reserve, not only their tags. This is how It looks like right now

[image: This is how its being shown]

And I want the fields "Name", "Room Category", etc. to be shown in the first view.

[image]

This is my desired result

[image]

This is how I actually have my code.

```
<page name="reservation_line" string='Reservation Line'>
        <field name="reservation_line" colspan="4" nolabel="1">
            <form string="Reservation Line">
                <separator string="Room Type"/>
                <field name="name" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="categ_id" colspan="4" nolabel="1"/>
                <newline/>
                <separator string="Select Room"/>
                <field
                    name="reserve"
                    colspan="4"
                    string="Room Number"
                    nolabel="1"
                />
            </form>
    
            <tree>
                <field
                    name="reserve"
                    string="Rooms"
                    widget="many2many_tags"
                />
            </tree>
    
    
        </field>
    </page>
    <page name="history" string='History'>
        <field name='folio_id' readonly='1'/>
    </page>
    <page name="comments" string='Comments'>
        <field name="comments"/>
    </page>
</notebook>
```

And this is the python class

```
Class HotelReservationLine(models.Model):

    _name = "hotel.reservation.line"
    _description = "Reservation Line"

    name = fields.Char("Name")
    line_id = fields.Many2one("hotel.reservation")
    reserve = fields.Many2many(
        "hotel.room",
        "hotel_reservation_line_room_rel",
        "hotel_reservation_line_id",
        "room_id",
        domain="[('isroom','=',True),\
                               ('categ_id','=',categ_id)]",
    )
    categ_id = fields.Many2one("hotel.room.type", "Room Type")
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace *widget="many2many_tags"* to *widget="one2many_list"*

If we want to display a list, just declare it as a normal field. For example:

```
<field name="reserve" string="Rooms"/>
```

It will bring all fields in the list and form a view. But if we want to display specific fields in a specific order, we need to declare field view in a following way:

```
<field name="reserve">
    <form>
        <!-- list of fields -->
    </form>
    <tree>
        <!-- list of fields -->
    </tree>
</field>
```